# How to automatically scroll a modal when reading log file

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When I open a modal by clicking on a button, I would like the scrollbar to automatically go to the bottom. I am reading the logfile as it is updated using XMLHTTP request. Below is the code:

```
<style>

/*  The following customizes the modal for logging */

.modal-backdrop {
    display:none;
}

.modal-open .modal {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#exampleModalLong {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;






}

.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;

  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;



  overflow-y: initial !important



}

.modal-body{
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: auto;


}




/*  old modal above */


   </style>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}', true);
      xhr.send();
      var position = 0;



      setInterval(function() {
        // output.textContent = xhr.responseText;
        var messages = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
    messages.slice(position, -1).forEach(function(value) {
        // latest.textContent = value;  // update the latest value in place
        // build and append a new item to a list to log all output
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = value;
        output.appendChild(item);

    });
    position = messages.length - 1;

    // $('#exampleModalLong').animate({ scrollTop: $('#exampleModalLong .modal-content').height() }, 'slow');
    // $("#exampleModalLong").animate({ scrollTop: $("#exampleModalLong").height() }, "slow");

  



      }, 500);
    });
  </script>

<body>

<!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle">
              <div class="modal-dialog  mw-100 w-75" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">DENA Logging</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- <pre id="output"></pre> -->
                    <ul id="output"></ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal -->

</body>
```

How to enforce the scrollbar to show the last item of the list from the bottom? I am using a modal to show the list of unordered items. This modal will be shown when a user clicks on a button.

Thank you!

Comment: I see your scroll is on the parent of output div, I have updated my answer below. Check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `modal-body` is the element that is getting scrolled, so just modifying `scrollBottom` of "modal-body" would do.

```
 ... // <--- commented out for sanity
setInterval(function() {
            // output.textContent = xhr.responseText;
            var messages = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
        messages.slice(position, -1).forEach(function(value) {
            // latest.textContent = value;  // update the latest value in place
            // build and append a new item to a list to log all output
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = value;
            output.appendChild(item);
            output.parentNode.scrollTop = output.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

after appending the item to `output` you can scroll the `output` div to the bottom like this:

```js
output.appendChild(item)

const modalBody = document.querySelector('.modal-body')
modalBody.scrollTop = modalBody.scrollHeight
```

Comment: It did not do anything to the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the div and set `scrollTop` equal to `scrollHeight`:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("divExample");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```